# Reversed IR LED receiver?

Tags: diodes, infrared, plc

Are there IR diodes out there? I do not need a reverse-bias IR receiver, I need the opposite (which I think will just result in a simple diode). Basically: When the sensor "sees" IR light I would like it to NOT allow current through. 
The reason I need something like this is because I would like to hook them up in parallel. This way the instant one of the diodes stop "seeing" IR light I can get a +5v (1) on my DAQ otherwise GRN (0).
Let me know if I'm going about this the totally wrong way.

Comment: Add a transistor to invert the signal?

Comment: The usual way to do this is to have independent input circuits for each receiver (which could be as simple as a one-transistor inverter), then add a logic circuit (which could be as simple as a diode network).

Comment: Alright, so would I use something like a NMOS NOT gate?

Comment: Technically, it would be called a NOR gate, but yes. You can also use an OR gate, and look for a high output.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like all I had to do was put them in series rather than parallel. This way as soon as one of the diodes breaks (ie stops seeing IR light) the current stops flowing through all of them in line and thus I stop seeing GRN.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi16Yk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This seems like the opposite of the original desire.

Comment: Your diodes are wired backwards.  The way you show, they will always conduct regardless of light.